# jQuery multiselect issues with IE

Tags: jquery

I've been working on implementing a multiselect solution which doesn't require the user to press CTRL to select multiple values but I've run into two problems that I would appreciate some help with. Hence I have **two questions** to ask :-)

1) The solution doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer. **How would I get it to work under IE?**

2) **How would I implement a clear button that unselects** all the options made apart from "Any"?

This is the code I have so far:

```
$('option').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    return false;
});
```

I've uploaded working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cC45d/

Comment: ever figure out how to get it to work in IE? I've currently got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Any` will always be the first option in the list, try this:

```
<button class="clear">Clear</button>
...
$('.clear').click(function(e) {
    $('#roomFac option').prop('selected', false);
    $('#roomFac option:first').prop('selected', true);
});
```